# Why ActionController::Metal leaks memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller

I have a following class:

```
class Myclass < ActionController::Metal
  def myaction
    huge_object.do_something
    # etc.
  end

  private
  def huge_object
    @obj ||= begin
      # allocate and initialize a ~10MB object
    end
  end
end
```

What I was amazed to find, is that even in production, each time the myaction is called, the object is allocated. Moreover, something is holding a reference to it, as the GC doesn't collect it. I made a workaround by wrapping the object in other class and including Singleton in that class. Still, I want to understand, what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

This was mentioned in a rails comment on github issues I think not long ago, you can search for it there. Long story short, it does this because the class variable does not stick around between requests.